# pandas table transformation from csv

Tags: python, list, pandas, transformation

Can you please help me with a problem i have with pandas, i want to export a list for excel so that it looks nice but cant

it should look like this:

```
 cut    AY1 AY2 A_ges
    0   values  values  values
    5   values  values  values
    10  values  values  values
    15  values  values  values
    20  values  values  values
    25  values  values  values
```

my data that i collect looks like this:

```
[name, cut, values]
['AY1', '+0.000', '25.71']
['AY1', '+5.000', '25.71']
['AY1', '+10.000', '26.0']
['AY1', '+15.000', '25.9']
['AY1', '+20.000', '25.85']
['AY1', '+25.000', '25.95']
['AY2', '+0.000', '26.01']
['AY2', '+5.000', '26.62']
['AY2', '+10.000', '26.55']
['AY2', '+15.000', '26.5']
['AY2', '+20.000', '26.56']
['AY2', '+25.000', '26.62']
['A_ges', '+0.000', '632.2']
['A_ges', '+5.000', '633.28']
['A_ges', '+10.000', '633.85']
['A_ges', '+15.000', '633.76']
['A_ges', '+20.000', '633.72']
['A_ges', '+25.000', '634.23']
```

Comment: How was created `list`s? Can you add code? Or lists are saved in  csv?

Comment: Given a list, you can convert to a DataFrame using `pd.DataFrame(list, columns=list[0])`

Comment: Is every record (e.g `['AY1', '+0.000', '25.71']`) of type list?

Comment: the lists come from a measuerement program, i only imported the csv data from that

Comment: @ Maria yes it is all the same

Comment: I'll rephrase, how's the csv structured? If you're openning it using excel for example, does 'name', 'cut' and 'values' appear in separate cells?

Answer (score 0):

I did change your input data to a list and there's probably a better way to solve this, but here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ['AY1', '+0.000', '25.71'],
        ['AY1', '+5.000', '25.71'],
        ['AY1', '+10.000', '26.0'],
        ['AY1', '+15.000', '25.9'],
        ['AY1', '+20.000', '25.85'],
        ['AY1', '+25.000', '25.95'],
        ['AY2', '+0.000', '26.01'],
        ['AY2', '+5.000', '26.62'],
        ['AY2', '+10.000', '26.55'],
        ['AY2', '+15.000', '26.5'],
        ['AY2', '+20.000', '26.56'],
        ['AY2', '+25.000', '26.62'],
        ['A_ges', '+0.000', '632.2'],
        ['A_ges', '+5.000', '633.28'],
        ['A_ges', '+10.000', '633.85'],
        ['A_ges', '+15.000', '633.76'],
        ['A_ges', '+20.000', '633.72'],
        ['A_ges', '+25.000', '634.23']
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

indices = df[1].unique()
cols = df[0].unique()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=indices, columns=cols)

grouped = df.groupby(by=1, axis=0)
for key,value in grouped:
    df2.loc[key,:] = value.loc[:,2].values

print(df2)
```

Comment: thanks a million, that is exactly what i need. im trying to understand it now as it works. thanks!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, could you please upvote and accept the answer?